# Forcing a claims refresh from STS to RP

Tags: .net-4.5, asp.net-mvc-5, wif, ws-federation

We have implemented a custom STS solution (there are sensible reasons in this, and I don't want to make this the point of the question). In this STS, the user can update his/her profile data (first name, last name, email, etc.) and by doing that, that same user obviously updates their own claims.

However, I am still trying to figure out how to notify RPs that there was a change in the claims for one particular user. I have checked other threads on SO regarding RP claims invalidation, and it seems that most answers relate or point to http://garrettvlieger.com/blog/2010/03/refreshing-claims-in-a-wif-claims-aware-application/.

However: this link is (1) old and (2) assumes the RP is doing the update, which in my case, it isn't.

So: how does one go about *pinging each RP to update its claims*? Is there a built-in mechanism, or do I have to roll my own?

**Sub-question 1:** an acceptable solution for me would be to invalidate each FedAuth cookie (on each RP), which means I just have to perform a massive sign-out out of all the RPs. Any thoughts on this, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing explicitly in the WS-Fed protocol for this. Think about it -- it's like a driver's license -- how can the DMV invalidate your license? They'd need some back-channel and not every RP would be in a position to check.

Perhaps you could trigger a signoutcleanup from the IdP -- that's certainly possible and would achieve what you're looking for in a forceful way.

Comment: The signout process sounds like a solution, but it would still require a reply channel to be established. Vittorio, from the WIF team, explained that in a custom STS, there is absolutely no tracking. That implied to me that if I were to use something built in, I would get that tracking...

Comment: Well, he just means that WIF doesn't implement that for you if you're building your own custom STS. So yes, you'd have to build it into your STS. We did in IdentityServer and it's not that difficult.